# Galilean Transformation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames, coordinate-systems, galilean-relativity

The transformation between inertial systems are given by affine transformations of $\mathbb{R}^{1+3}$. These are given by $t'=\lambda t+\vec{c}^\top \vec{x} +a$ and $\vec{x}'=\vec{v}t+M\vec{x}+\vec{b}$ where M is a matrix. 
But the Galilean transformations do not include the $\vec{c}^\top\vec{x}$ term in the time part.This means $\vec{c}=0$. Why is it, that this holdes ? I can't find an argument for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument is that in Galilean transformation you *assume* time to be absolute. Translating this requirement in an operative statement, you want intervals of time between to events to be invariant under the transformation from a reference system to another. In formulas
$$
\Delta t = \Delta t' \quad\to\quad
 t_2-t_1 = t_2'-t_1' = \lambda\Delta t + \vec{c}^T\Delta\vec{x}
$$
where $\Delta\vec{x}$ is the spatial distance between two events and the $t$s  are the corresponding times. Given the hypothesis, if the equality must hold for whatever passage between frames, than it must be $\vec{c}=0$ and $\lambda=1$. The only transformation of time allowed is the addition of a constant parameter $a$ appearing in the general transformation you wrote, which is physically just a time shift in the synchronization procedure of the clocks of the different references.